# Classes and Objects for stock and forex prices

Tags: python, arrays, class, object

I have forex price data stored in a bunch of .csv files, and I want to use Python to create classes and objects to store the price information of every pair in a useful way.

Every tick is and instant in time, every tick has 6 variables: date, open, high, low, close, and volume.

So far I have been able to create a class, loaded the data, store it in a  2D numpy array, and create an array of objects that stores all the information of one pair in that array.

My current issue is that I want to create an object of objects, where each object is the information of every pair of the 27 that I am currently using. Each pair has different sizes (maybe one pair has 10000 ticks and another has 3000). So I dont know which kind of data structure can store arrays of objects of different sizes, so later on it is practical to iterate over it.

The final object should look like this.

Final_object = [EUR-USD, USD-CAD, .....],  totally 27 pairs

EUR-USD: it is an array of objets (the object is every single tick) of size 10000.

USD-CAD: it is an array of objets (the object is every single tick) of size 3000.

Once Final_object is created I will provide another object (lets call it M), that has 2 dimensions (27 columns) and each column has the amount of rows corresponding the size of every element of Final_object.

For example: lets say its 3 pairs instead of 27.
Final object: [EUR-USD, USD-CAD, AUD-USD]

EUR-USD: size 10000.

USD-CAD: size 3000.

AUD-USD: size 6000

M: [array of size 10000, array of size 3000, array of size 3000]

And I want to use M to iterate over Final_object.

This is what I have done so far.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

_ = "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
print(_)  # --------------------------------------------------------------------

# creating a class.
class T:
    def __init__(self, date, open, high, low, close, volume):
        self.date = date
        self.open = open
        self.high = high
        self.low = low
        self.close = close
        self.volume = volume

    def __repr__(self):

        return "The data for this tick is ('{}', {}, {}, {}, {}, {})".format(self.date, self.open, self.high, self.low,
                                                                             self.close, self.volume)

# creating one tick
tick1 = T("10-12-1987", 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
print(tick1)

# creating another tick
tick2 = T("11-12-1987", 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
print(tick2)

print(_)  # --------------------------------------------------------------------

# creating np arrays with attributes
B = np.array([tick1.open, tick2.open])
F = np.array([tick1.date, tick2.date])
print(B)
print(F)

print(_)  # --------------------------------------------------------------------

# loading data from a .csv file
Raw_data = pd.read_csv("EURUSDDaily.csv", header=None, encoding = 'utf-16')
print(Raw_data)
print(Raw_data[0])
print(Raw_data.tail(5))

print(_)  # --------------------------------------------------------------------

# selecting data from the dataframe
print(Raw_data.iloc[-2])
print(Raw_data[0][1:12680])

Np_array = Raw_data.to_numpy()
Np_array2= Np_array[:,0:-1]
print(Np_array2)


temp = Np_array2[-1]

tick3 = T(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], temp[4], temp[5])
print(tick3)

# creating an array of objects
obj_array = []
for i in range(np.size(Np_array,0)):
    temp = Np_array2[i]
    obj = T(temp[0], temp[1], temp[2], temp[3], temp[4], temp[5])
    obj_array.append(obj)
```

The objective of this exercise is to learn about classes and objects. There must be tons of modules that do what I am trying to do in a better way.

I also would appreciate any advice regarding improving the current code.

Thank you.

Comment: What is the *specific* problem you're having?

Comment: I don't know what is the inmediate next step. How do I create an object of objects, where each object has different sizes, and iterate over it?

Comment: An array of objects *is an object of objects*. Everything is an object. Now, using a `numpy.ndarray` with dtype `object` is not a good use of `numpy`. Because now it is basically a less performant list.

Comment: Anyway, it's really not clear to me what you are trying to create exactly, but you say "how do I create an object of objects where each object is different sizes", well, you do pretty much the same thing like you did with your `T` class for T objects (which are objects of objects...).